# How to check, if the ListView changed after data update

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onscroll

I have one unsolved question, which I couldn't accomplish to answer myself. Is there any way, how to check, if the ListView (`ListView.getCount();`) changed after updating the data - more accurately, after load-more process. I want to remove the footer view (`ProgressBar`) after the ListView stays the same after my update method.

Is there any way how to do it?

If necessary, check short codes below

Thanks in advance!

My method, which adds more data:

```
public void updateData() {
    mListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.animal_list);     
    final ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
    query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY);
    query.orderByAscending("animal");
    query.setLimit(mListView.getCount() + 5);

    Log.v("updateData", "uploading data from Parse.com");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

            if(animals != null){
                mAdapter.clear();
                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);  
                footie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mAdapter.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {

                    mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));

                }  

            }  
        }
    }); 
}
```

My OnScrollListener, which finds out, that the data have to be updated:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                         int totalItemCount) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
        int scrollState) {

        int threshold = 1;
        int count = mListView.getCount();

        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold){

                updateData();
                //here do I need to add - if ListView didnt change - > remove footer                        
            }

        }
        if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == scrollState) {
            View currentFocus = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

            if(currentFocus != null) {
                currentFocus.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Just put `list size` in temp variable, and check `temp variable values < list.size` just after `updateData()` called, if yes then remove `footerview`.

Comment: what do you mean by temp variables?

Comment: He mean: you should save the size of the list view in a variable (before the changes happen) and then when everything is ready you should check the new size with the size saved in the variable. If it's changed, do what you want. Maybe he now is writing an answer.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly, what I wanted to do. And how to get the size before and after? i just wrote `int before = mListView.getCount();` and after the method `int after = mListView.getCount();` and if(after == before) -> do something... but id didnt work

Comment: found any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the adapter and set the data separately.

```
public void updateData() {
    ...

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

            if(animals != null){
                mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout footie = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.footerview);  
                footie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mAdapter.setItems(animals);
            }  
        }
    }); 
}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public void setItems(List<Animal> animals) {
        int oldCount = getCount();
        int newCount = animals.size();
        clear();
        addAll(animals);
        if (oldCount != newCount) {
            // Do whatever you want here. The number of items changed.
        }
    }
}
```